# use admin is not working in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have to pass parameter from a shell script to mongo javascript

So I am trying like:

```
mongo --eval "var ADMIN_USER_NAME='$ADMIN_NAME', ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD='$ADMIN_PASSWORD'" insertusers.js
```

and `insertusers.js` contains:

```
cat insertusers.js

use admin

db.addUser( { user: ADMIN_USER_NAME,
          pwd: ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD,
          roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )
```

However I am getting

```
mongo --eval "var ADMIN_USER_NAME='$ADMIN_NAME', ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD='$ADMIN_PASSWORD'"     insertusers.js
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Fri Apr 11 21:30:34.791 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at insertusers.js:5
failed to load: insertusers.js
```

I am not understanding why it is failing. Same thing can be run from javascript schell and that works.

Whenever it is hitting `use admin` line, it is showing `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "use admin" command is likely your problem as it involves changing some user space variables.

Try the following

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").addUser( { user: ADMIN_USER_NAME,
      pwd: ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD,
      roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )
```

Comment: Things like "use ..." are not valid javascript and cannot be used in a javascript file. They are part of the mongo REPL shell, and not to be used in anything but an interactive shell session. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo